# Identity Server 3.0 enable counter for login failed

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

Is it possible to turn on incrementing login fails attempt for table AspNetUsers in Identity Server 3. I don't want to implement own method to authenticate user. Is it possible via some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you have to write your own custom user service. Check the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html) for the service.